# <Assembly> uses Microsoft.Synchronization which has a higher version than referenced assembly

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error building my C# project.

> Assembly "name_of_assembly" uses 'Microsoft.Synchronization,
>   Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly
>   'Microsoft.Synchronization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

I have made sure all my class libraries are targeting the same version of .NET framework which typically seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I examined the installed programs and found I had version 1.0 and 2.1 of Microsoft Sync Framework installed. I uninstalled version 1 components. That fixed the problem.

Now my code builds fine.

There are several components for each version in installed programs. I uninstalled two of v1.0 but still have its Runtime component  but code already builds fine.

If you only have v1 installed, uninstall it and install the correct version, version 2.1 is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19502).